# Dart: Getter returns null even after calling async Setter (made sure it the field was not null inside the method)

Tags: flutter, dart

It feels so simple and yet it doesn't work. Am I missing something very fundamental here? These getters and setters Methods are in class AppData which has a static field: List (element type LatLng) _navRoute = List(); For some reason get always returns null.

```
static void setNewRoute() async{
  List<LatLng> navRoute = await _googleMapPolyline.getCoordinatesWithLocation(
    origin: LatLng(_currentLocation.latitude, _currentLocation.longitude),
    destination: LatLng(_navDestination.latitude, _navDestination.longitude),
    mode: RouteMode.walking
  );
  _navRoute = navRoute;
  print("Nav route in set route is:" + _navRoute.toString()); //does not print null
}

static List<LatLng> getNavRoute(){
   print("Nav route in get route is:" + _navRoute.toString()); //prints null 
  return _navRoute; //returns null
}
```

The way I am calling the these function is:

```
onPressed: (){
            setState(() {
              AppData.updateCurrentLocation();
              AppData.setNavDestination(widget._latitude, widget._longitude);
              AppData.setNewRoute();
              AppData.setNavStatus(true);
            });
            print("Current location is: " + AppData.getCurrentLocation().latitude.toString() + " , " + AppData.getCurrentLocation().longitude.toString()); //Not null
            print("Nav destination is: " + AppData.getNavDestination().latitude.toString()+ ", " + AppData.getNavDestination().longitude.toString()); //Not null
            print("Nav is: " + AppData.getNavRoute().toString()); //Always null
            Navigator.pop(context); //pop the bottomModalSheet
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context, 
                new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => AppData.getTour(widget._tourID),
                ),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of issues here.

First, your `async` methods should return `Future`, as all `async` methods are expected to return `Future`:

```dart
static Future<void> setNewRoute() async{
...
}
```

Second, you need to `await` your `Future`s:

```dart
onPressed: (){
            setState(() async {
              AppData.updateCurrentLocation();
              AppData.setNavDestination(widget._latitude, widget._longitude);
              // This will complete once you've actually set _navRoute
              await AppData.setNewRoute();
              AppData.setNavStatus(true);
            });
            print("Current location is: " + AppData.getCurrentLocation().latitude.toString() + " , " + AppData.getCurrentLocation().longitude.toString()); //Not null
            print("Nav destination is: " + AppData.getNavDestination().latitude.toString()+ ", " + AppData.getNavDestination().longitude.toString()); //Not null
            print("Nav is: " + AppData.getNavRoute().toString()); //Always null
            Navigator.pop(context); //pop the bottomModalSheet
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context, 
                new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => AppData.getTour(widget._tourID),
                ),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Basically `AppData.getNavRoute` is returning `null` since `_navRoute` hasn't actually been set yet as you didn't wait for the asynchronous operation it depends on to complete.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. It didn't quite work but, your answer helped me find out the mistake. I will add an answer to this.To clarify: it threw an assertion about having call to async function inside change state

Answer (score 1):

Changed setter signature to Future void and onPressed to:

```
onPressed: () async{
            AppData.updateCurrentLocation();
            AppData.setNavDestination(widget._latitude, widget._longitude);
            AppData.setNavStatus(true);
            await AppData.setNewRoute();
            setState(() {
            });
            print("Current location is: " + AppData.getCurrentLocation().latitude.toString() + " , " + AppData.getCurrentLocation().longitude.toString());
            print("Nav destination is: " + AppData.getNavDestination().latitude.toString()+ ", " + AppData.getNavDestination().longitude.toString());
            Navigator.pop(context); //pop the bottomModalSheet
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context, 
                new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => AppData.getTour(widget._tourID),
                ),
            );
          },
```

And it works.